# DynamoDB: mapper and transactions using java SDK

Tags: sdk, amazon-web-services, transactions, amazon-dynamodb

I am developing a project in Java, and I am using the AWS SDK.
I am using Dynamo DB.
I am using the mapper, and it is very useful for me because I can perform basic operation directly on a java entity.

Recently, I have seen the library that allows to add transactionality to Dyanamo DB: https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-transactions

Such library works really fine, but it does not allow me to use the mapper. It only works with GetRequest, PutRequest, ...

I have no problem when getting results, because I can use the method "marshallIntoObject(Class, Map)" for obtaining the java entity from the results of a query.

How can I perform the same operation for saving/updating an item?
I would really like to have a method that takes in input a java entity and converts it to a Map. 
I would use the returned map for performing query through the transaction engine.
Is it available somewhere?

Moreover, are there any plans to make the project "dynamodb-transactions" able to support the mapper?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementation of Atomic Transactions in dynamodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664966/implementation-of-atomic-transactions-in-dynamodb)

Answer (score 11):

Following up on this: The linked feature request has now been [implemented](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-transactions/commit/6bc6b89b01fe6d2e483718a7dc0d752682260bf4).

The DynamoDB transaction library now supports using the DynamoDB Mapper.  Take a look at the examples and the javadocs to get started with it, and feel free to open questions in the github project if you have any.

Comment: Hey David, Is this implemented for Android SDK as well? I tried to add `compile 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2:amazon-dynamodb-transactions:1.1.2'` in my build.gradle but android studio is unable to find the artifact!

Answer (score 0):

You could start by looking at how DynamoDB parses objects before saving.
You can view [DynamoDBMapper](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/30f83776c0fff03833ee8235f0c9d23cffa0d8e2/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.java) code on GitHub. You're should be looking for the protected class `SaveObjectHandler` implementations in the function `save`

Questions / Feature requests should be either logged at the issues section of the project on GitHub ([There's one already for supporting DynamoDBMapper](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-transactions/issues/5)) or discussed in the [AWS DynamoDB forum](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-transactions/issues/5)

Comment: Yes, I looked at the source code you mentioned, but there is not a public method to call, and the flow of the logic is not simple enough to be reused outside the original class. I posted the answer on the Aws DynamoDB forum, I'll update this post if someone should give me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - AWS launched DynamoDBMapper support for the built-in transactions API library (launched at re:Invent 2018): https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/dynamodbmapper-now-supports-amazon-dynamodb-transactional-api-calls/

Comment: Better as a comment.

Comment: Agreed should be converted to a comment.